# sbrk system call in unix

Tags: c, linux, bash, unix

I studied like  malloc uses the sbrk system call. But, some one says, the sbrk is
deprecated one. Now a days malloc using the mmap2 system call to allocate
memory. So, Is there any commands like (ls,cat, grep, sed) using the sbrk
system call. For Ex:

```
mohanraj@ltsp63:~/Development/chap8$ strace -c ls
a.out  files  flush.c  fopen.c      ld.c  lld.c  malloc.c  opendir1.c  t2.c  t3.c  t.c  test.c
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
  -nan    0.000000           0        12           read
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           write
  -nan    0.000000           0        13           open
  -nan    0.000000           0        16           close
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           execve
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           time
  -nan    0.000000           0         9         8 access
  -nan    0.000000           0         3           brk
  -nan    0.000000           0         3           ioctl
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           readlink
  -nan    0.000000           0         5           munmap
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           uname
  -nan    0.000000           0        11           mprotect
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           _llseek
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           getsid
  -nan    0.000000           0         2           rt_sigaction
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           rt_sigprocmask
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           getcwd
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           getrlimit
  -nan    0.000000           0        28           mmap2
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           stat64
  -nan    0.000000           0        16           fstat64
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           getuid32
  -nan    0.000000           0         2           getdents64
  -nan    0.000000           0         1         1 futex
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           set_thread_area
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           statfs64
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           openat
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           set_robust_list
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           socket
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           connect
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           send
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000000                   141         9 total
mohanraj@ltsp63:~/Development/chap8$
```

The above output shows that the ls command using the above syscall to 
execute the output. Likewise any command using the sbrk system call, Is there
any what is that?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Almost all programs just use `malloc()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sbrk` is not a system call in linux. It's a library function implemented in libc which uses the `brk` system call. Your strace shows `brk` being used.

Answer (score 1):

If in **libc** a malloc implementation is redirecited to **mmap** instead of **sbrk**. Then every call to malloc will result in mmap. And you can find sbrk only if it is **explicitly** used in user level application (normally malloc is used)

Comment: It's highly unlikely that _every_ call to `malloc()` will result in a `mmap`.   Implementations will try to satisfy `malloc()` by carving space out of larger chunks of mmap()ed memory.